# Java 7 NIO / JPathWatch issue - moving directories in Windows

Tags: java, windows, nio, watchservice

I have implemented an application which uses Java NIO's `WatchService` to monitor changes to files and folders in a directory tree. Running on Windows XP, all filesystem changes are being picked up - apart from moving a directory into the monitored tree by dragging-and-dropping in Explorer.

Events are picked up for cutting and pasting a directory (ctrl+x, ctrl+v), just not drag-and-drop (**edit** - see update below).

I have reimplemented the solution using [JPathWatch](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/), however this suffers from the same issue.

I am registering the standard `ENTRY_CREATE`, `ENTRY_DELETE` and `ENTRY_MODIFY` and am additionally using the curious-underdocumented `com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedWatchEventModifier` to avoid other issues when the application is being run on Windows.

Save for polling - which I really don't want to do - does anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

Issue is with moving files in general - I was mistaken about ctrl+x/ctrl+v working. See solution below for explanation.

Comment: Please, take the time to enter a bug report for java too. As you seem to have found out other things too, that would make the java community benefit.

Comment: Can you try it on a newer version of windows to determine if it likely to be a bug in Java or Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a test case demonstrated that the original suspicion was incorrect - the issue was with *any* file move operation under Windows.

The underlying issue appears to be that using the `ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE` modifier on Windows recursively monitors all child directories when a parent directory is copied - but not moved.

When a directory is moved a `ENTRY_CREATE` is registered on the parent directory only, so my solution was to remove `FILE_TREE` and recursively monitor directories manually.

There is a caveat, and this is a bit of a lose/lose situation - the reason why `FILE_TREE` was used in the first place was to allow monitoring of recursive deletion of directory trees. If directories are manually recursively watched, a file lock is placed on the child directories. This prevents users from deleting the parent directory without deleting the child directories first.

Using `FILE_TREE` means that a lock is only obtained on the parent folder, so the full tree can be deleted by users.

Using JPathWatch instead of Java 7 NIO results in identical behaviour re: file locks and the inability for users to recursively delete a directory tree.

The **final, usable solution** was to use a polling approach with Apache Commons IO's monitoring classes, based off [this example](http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/) (but with an additional infinite loop after `monitor.start()`, as this doesn't block as is implied.